# Proper way to pass server variables to client in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In the past, I usually have just embedded the values I need passed into html data elements and then read them from there via JavaScript. However, I know there's a more proper way to do so.  In particular, I'd like to learn how implement the first method mentioned in [this blog post](http://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/02/05/passing-net-server-side-data-to-javascript). However, I'd also like to know what the best way to pass data from server-side to client side is when you're not using ajax.

EDIT: Since I'm still pretty unsure, let me explain what I'm trying do to. I'm creating a page with a lot of dynamic content on it that is dependent on reading from a database. I want to be able to load the page's static content first. Then, using jQuery, I want to make an ayschronous HTTP get request to the server to read from the database and retrieve the information I need. Finally, if I need more information from the database, I want to be able to request the server for more information without having to reload the page.

Comment: What type of data (volume/complexity) are you shipping to the client-side? That link gives most of the options, but the choice depends on the specific situation.

Comment: In response to your edit, Web API seems clear as the way forward. It is *the* technology for responding to AJAX requests in an ASP.NET environment.

Answer (score 0):

"When you're not using ajax"!?!? - Start!

If you're dead set on not making a service request to the server, there are the following ways:

Hidden form fields - so <input type=hidden value=xyz >

PageMethods - ok this is ajax, but it's simple, see here http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.2>http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.2

Best way.... is to do it properly, implement webapi and send down JSON then on the client end interpret that with Javascript.

Edit: your edit paints a different picture. I thought you just wanted a single piece of data, but it sounds like you need a proper api, so go with webapi, and use jQuery to make the calls, then populate through code, or jQuery templates(the best option).

Comment: Please don't recommend Page Methods for new code. That technology is deprecated and no longer supported (and never worked all that well). [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) is the replacement technology.

Comment: I agree, it  didn't work that well, and that webapi is a much better way of doing things. However, it's not deprecated (and is still in .net 4.5, and not marked as such). Or do you mean "deprecated" like "webforms" is deprecated? as in "IT ISN'T" but some people like to think so?

Comment: [John Saunders](http://stackoverflow.com/users/76337/john-saunders) has an [excellent blog post](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/) detailing why you shouldn't use it.

Comment: That blog is about asmx, and why you should use WCF instead (which is certainly not my recommendation).  PageMethods != ASMX...  I presumed OP was using webforms and just wanted to pass some data down to the client - webforms has a method for doing that, PageMethods.

Comment: The blog was perhaps poorly titled-WebMethods (ASMX) and PageMethods are using the same technology stack and you should use neither for new development. The blog did suggest using WCF as an alternative, but it was also written in 2011 when Web API did not exist. The main takeway from the article is that WebMethod and PageMethod are legacy, unsupported, and should not be used. And no, page methods are no improvement over what the OP is already doing. Sorry, will have to downvote your answer if you continue to suggest using old unsupported technology.

Comment: Microsoft make no indication that pagemethods are deprecated or no longer supported, and are in fact fully supported in 4.5. So your wild claim seems somewhat baseless. No point in going in circles, we'll have to agree to differ.

Comment: As I pointed out, page methods use the same exact technology as web methods. Both of which Microsoft has said they're no longer reporting. John provided the links to where Microsoft has said this in his blog entry. While the API's are still present in .NET 4.5, this is solely to make it possible to upgrade to 4.5 without breaking existing applications. New development should *not* be done using those web services, and you should certainly not be recommending them in your answer.